# How to drop rows in pandas with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID      description      log       
 1       104              motherboardsrno123
 2       104              displaysrno456
 3       107              1234
 4       108              53455
 5       104              pulsersrno2333
 6       108              53456
 7       109              NA
```

I want to keep only those rows which contains 'mother' or 'pulser' in description 104

Following is my desired dataframe

```
ID      description      log       
 1       104              motherboardsrno123
 3       107              1234
 4       108              53455
 5       104              pulsersrno2333
 6       108              53456
 7       109              NA
```

I am doing following in pandas

```
   df= df[(df.log.str.contains("mother|pulsar",na=True)) and (df.description == '104')]
```

But this is not giving me required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need change second string to `pulser`, change `and` to `&` for bitwise AND and if necessary compare by integer `104` (not string `'104'`, but it depends of data):

```
df = df[(df.log.str.contains("mother|pulser", na=True)) & (df.description == 104)]
print (df)
   ID  description                 log
0   1          104  motherboardsrno123
4   5          104      pulsersrno2333
```

For your expected output - get `mother or pulser` or not `104`:

```
df= df[(df.log.str.contains("mother|pulser", na=True)) | (df.description != 104)]

print (df)
   ID  description                 log
0   1          104  motherboardsrno123
2   3          107                1234
3   4          108               53455
4   5          104      pulsersrno2333
5   6          108               53456
6   7          109                 NaN
```

Comment: `df = df[(df.log.str.contains("mother|pulser", na=True)) | (df.description != 104)]
` this is giving me dataframe without 104 in it.

Comment: @Neil hmmmm, what is `print (df.description.dtype)` ?

Comment: `description` datatype is string

Comment: Then `104` should be `'104'`

Comment: Yes I did that. But still it is removing all `104`